How to fix util.get_platform() mismatch with MacOS version
I am trying to install torch 2.3.1 on Apple M2, macOS Sonoma 14.4.
On https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/4484 it shows that python 3.11.4 works and so I have created a conda environment with 3.11.4. However, there is still an error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=2.3.1 (from samv2) (from versions: 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=2.3.1

I tried to download the exact wheel mentioned in the issue to pip install it: pip install /Users/yllow/Downloads/torch-2.3.1-cp311-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
However there is an error:
ERROR: torch-2.3.1-cp311-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

It turns out that
>>> from distutils import util
>>> util.get_platform()
'macosx-10.9-x86_64'

What should I do to fix this please?

I didn't fix it but went around the problem by exiting from my conda environment (conda deactivate) and brew install python which brought me to 3.12.6.
